# Program will not build

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to build a program and I'm getting the error:

```
Error   2   An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Release\app.publish\\setup.exe. SignTool Error: ISignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x80880253

    The signer's certificate is not valid for signing.

SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Release\app.publish\\setup.exe  program1
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check your certificates it exist or not

[View or manage your certificates](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/View-or-manage-your-certificates)

To solve this problem in Visual Studio

1. Right click on the project and selected Properties.
2. Click on tag Signing.
3. And check the checkbox next to Sign the ClickOnce manifests.
4. Press the button Create Test Certificate... and followed
   The process.

[image]